# Deferring computation in paginated lists with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockoutjs 2.0 with the deferred-updates plugin. I have a view that is designed to paginate a list, as follows:

```
function PaginatedView(label, items, size) {
    var self = this;

    this.label = ko.observable(label);

    // List of all items to display
    this.list = ko.observableArray(items);

    // List that contains the items on the current page
    this.rows = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.pageSize = ko.observable(size || 5);
    this.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);

    function populateList() {
        var size = self.pageSize();
        var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
        self.rows( self.list.slice(start, start + size) );
        console.log(self.label() + ": Set rows to range", start, start + size - 1);
    }

    // if the deferEvaluation value is true, no items are ever displayed
    ko.computed(populateList, null, {deferEvaluation: false});    

    this.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function() {
        return Math.ceil(this.list().length / this.pageSize()) - 1;
    }, this);

    this.pageList = ko.computed(function() {
        var pages = [];
        for (var p = 0; p <= self.maxPageIndex(); p++)
            pages.push(p+1);

        return pages;
    });

    this.goToPage = function(p) {
        p--;
        if (p>=0 && p<=self.maxPageIndex())
            self.pageIndex(p);
    }
};
```

In my application, I create multiple views that paginate through different lists of objects. For the purposes of tracking which items people actually see, I would like to defer the computation of the pagination (in the `populateList()` function above) until the view is actually ready to be displayed.

I thought I could achieve this with the deferred-updates plugin by setting the `deferEvaluation` option to false. But if I do that, I see no output at all. I've built a small [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/ruBwu/) with jsfiddle to illustrate the problem. With the value set to false, the console will show two lines of output before any list is selected; with the value set to true, no list elements are ever displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line:

```
ko.computed(populateList, null, {deferEvaluation: false});
```

creates an anonymous computed observable (as it's not assigned to anything). As it's never assigned it isn't read anywhere. With deferEvaluation true, the inner function (populateList)  doesn't get run until something tries to read the computed observable, which of course won't happen!

If you don't use deferEvaluation, you're still throwing away the reference, but populateList will get called immediately when you define your computed observable. In this case, the knockout dependency tracking will realise that your anonymous computed observable depends on things like 'pageSize', it will also realise that the computed observable updates the 'rows' variable, i.e. that 'rows' is dependent on the computed observable. Enough is then setup for it to work, but it's not ideal.

I think the way I'd fix it is:

First, change the populateList function to return an array:

```
function populateList() {
    var size = self.pageSize();
    var start = self.pageIndex() * size;
    var result = self.list.slice(start, start + size);
    console.log(self.label() + ": Set rows to range", start, start + size - 1);
    return result;
}
```

Then call the computed observable rows:

```
this.rows = ko.computed(populateList, null, {deferEvaluation: false});
```

Comment: I can't have rows be a computed variable because I need to be able to sort it. I suppose I could have two variables, a `ko.computed` and a `ko.observableArray`, that store the same items. A bit inefficient, but might be what I need.

Comment: Do you need to sort `rows` independently of `list`? (i.e. can you just apply the sort to `list` and `rows` will already be sorted?)